# Better to convert strings to arrays before transforming (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string

I've been working through some simple JavaScript challenges at Coderbyte. One of them is to take a string and capitalize the first letter of each word. I've solved this a couple of ways. First by converting the words to arrays, and second by "manipulating" the strings themselves. I am wondering if either of these options is preferred? That is, I've received some feedback suggesting that manipulating strings is usually not a great idea because they are immutable, which means I am not really manipulating strings but rather replacing one string with another. I'm not exactly sure why this is a bad thing. Maybe its a memory issue or a speed issue? Anyway, my solutions are below. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 

  str = str.split(" ");
  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    str1 = str[i].split("");
    str1[0] = str1[0].toUpperCase();
    str[i] = str1.join("");
  }
  str = str.join(" ");
  return str;        
}

function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
  str = str.split(" ");
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  console.log(str[i].length);
    str[i]=str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+str[i].slice(1,str[i].length);
  }
  str = str.join(" ");
  return str; 
}
```

Comment: you can use array notation on strings, no need to split.

Comment: you don't need arrays or loops: return str.replace(/\s+([a-z])/g, function(j,a){return a.toUpperCase();})

Comment: 1) When I removed the split and join statements, the words were not capitalized. 2) It seems like most of these challenges can be solved more efficiently with a regular expression. I am still a little uncertain with these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the performance difference isn't worth worrying about..UNLESS you find yourself capitalizing millions of words at a time, but then maybe you shouldn't be using javascript to solve the problem.

While strings are immutable, simple string concatenation should still be less expensive than converting to an array and back to a string just to modify one element.

When using javascript I prefer readability over microscopic performance gains.

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
    return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

I modified the jsperf [here](http://jsperf.com/capitalize-first-letter-2/2), and it turns out that this is quite faster than the other two as well.

Comment: Did you see the test that @ksnabb ran? These seem like significant differences. In real world applications, I don't know if this is meaningful but the chart is striking. I don't need to define an endpoint in my slice, do I? if I leave the second parameter blank it slices to the end of the word.

Comment: This jsperf is very nice. I had never seen it before. I created a third test because I wasn't quite sure we were comparing apple to apples. Here are my results http://jsperf.com/capitalize-first-letter-3

Comment: @Nathan, Your tests aren't actually executing the functions, only creating them in each test.

Comment: Oops...what about now? Not sure I know how to set this up properly. http://jsperf.com/capitalize-first-letter-3/2

Answer (score 1):

The best practices are to make sure it is readable, works in the browsers / platforms you aim to support and that the execution speed is fast. Speed is the easy one so I added your code to this jsPerf and also found another jsPerf about capitalizing the first letter:

Your code examples:
http://jsperf.com/capitalize-first-letter-2

Others jsPerf about the same thing:
http://jsperf.com/capitalize-first-letter

Comment: Wow, the bar chart makes it look like the array approach is significantly faster.